# Overide Magento extension layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, overrides, xml

I have problem with overriding Magento extension Front-end layout. I have installed extension [Youama Ajax Login and Register](https://github.com/DoveID/Magento-Ajax-Login). Now I need to override layout of login and register.

My `app/code/local/Tech/Theme/etc/config.xml` file :

```
<frontend>
<layout>
        <updates>
            <tech_theme>
                <file>tech_ajaxlogin.xml</file>
            </tech_theme>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

My tech_ajaxlogin.xml file contain same default extension xml (copied file) and changed

```
            <action ifconfig="youamaajaxlogin/settings/power"
                    method="setTemplate">
                <template>ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.phtml</template>
            </action>
```

And ajaxlogin.phtml file in `app/design/frontend/rwd/tech/template/ajaxlogin` path.

Now I'm confused where exactly `tech_ajaxlogin.xml` file should be located to override base xml file. I have tried in many places. But no luck.

Any help appreciated

**Edited:**

`Config.xml` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Tech_Theme>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Tech_Theme>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <tech_theme>
                <class>Tech_Theme_Block</class>
            </tech_theme>
        </blocks>
    <helpers>
            <tech_theme>
                <class>Tech_Theme_Helper</class>
            </tech_theme>  
        </helpers>
    <models>
            <tech_theme>
                <class>Tech_Theme_Model</class>

            </tech_theme>
            <youama_ajaxlogin>
                <rewrite>
                    <!-- Model -->
                    <ajaxregister>Tech_Theme_Model_Ajaxregister</ajaxregister>
                </rewrite>
            </youama_ajaxlogin>

        </models>

    </global>
    <frontend>
    <layout>
            <updates>
                <tech_theme>
                    <file>tech_ajaxlogin.xml</file>
                </tech_theme>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be under your app/design/frontend/base/default/layout folder.

I suggest you change your layout file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="youamaajaxlogin">
          <action ifconfig="youamaajaxlogin/settings/power"
                    method="setTemplate">
                <template>ajaxlogin/ajaxlogin.phtml</template>
            </action>
       </reference>
    <default>
</layout>
```

Try making your module dependent:

app/etc/modules/Tech_Theme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tech_Theme>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends><Youama_Ajaxlogin/></depends>
        </Tech_Theme>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: I have placed there but it is not reflecting

Comment: See my edited post. I reckon you try to avoid copy/pasting the exact same layout from the original module as it would conflict.

Comment: I have changed xml file. But It doesn't look like it is overridding xml file. Block is still rendering if any error is there in this xml file

Comment: Could you post full content of your config.xml file please ? Also could try making your module depends on the original module in your app/etc/modules xml file ?

Comment: I have edited. How to make module depends on the original module which is extension in app/etc/modules xml file?

Comment: See my edited solution.

Comment: Still it is not working. I'm using rwd package. Does this effects?